# Definition of weak solution in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have a problem:

> For $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\Bbb R^n$. We consider
>   $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
> \Delta u-\lambda u =f  \ \rm in \ \Omega & \\ 
>   u\mid_{\partial {\Omega}} =0
> \end{matrix}\right. \tag I$$
>
> - a/ Definition of *classical solution*;
> - b/ Definition of *weak solution* in the $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ space.
>
> Finding the conditions so that *weak solution* becomes *classical solution*.
>
> - c/ Prove that if $\lambda=0$ then $(I)$ has a unique solution in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$;
> - d/ Determine the **existence and uniqueness** of solution of $(I)$ by $\lambda$.

==============================================

I'm not sure but I still write it here:

*) **For a): Definition of classical solution**

Let $f \in C^{0}(\Omega)$. A function $u \in C^{2}(\Omega) \cap C^0(\overline{\Omega})$ such that $(I)$ forall $x \in \overline{\Omega}$.

*) **For b): Definition of *weak solution* in the $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ space**

Let $f \in H^{-1}(\Omega)=(H_{0}^{1}(\Omega))^*$. A function $u$ such that:

$$\Delta u - \lambda u=f  \ \rm in \ \Omega \iff
\left \langle \Delta u - \lambda u,\varphi  \right \rangle=\left \langle f,\varphi  \right \rangle \  \text{for any test function} \ \varphi \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$$

- Finding the conditions so that *weak solution* becomes *classical solution*:

For $f \in H^k(\Omega)$ and $\partial \Omega \subset C^{k+2}(\Omega)\implies u \in H^{k+2}(\Omega)\cap H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$.

If $k+2>\dfrac{n}{2}+2 \implies k>\dfrac{n}{2}$. By applying **Sobolev embedding theorem**, we have $u \in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$. Because $$H^{k+2}(\Omega)\overset{\rm embedding}{\rightarrow} C^2(\overline{\Omega})$$...

===============================================

Now, I have stuch when I go on...Can anyone help me!

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What techniques do you know to prove existence of solutions for this type of PDE?

Comment: Did I have the correct definitions of classical solution and weak solution for $(I)$?

Comment: If $f \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ then $(I)$ has a unique weak  solution $u \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, (if $\lambda =0$). Is it correct? **Tomás**. But I don't know How can we prove existence of solutions for this type of PDE! :(

Comment: To prove existence, you have know some technique. There are plenty of them: Minimization, Fredholm Alternative, Monotone Operators and so on. Do you know any of these approachs?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know :( Or I forgot it, maybe! Can you say about it? Thanks!

Comment: To help you, I need to know your background. Are you making some course? Are you studying alone?

Comment: Yes, thanks **Tomás**.I have a course. And that is the question from my professor, but I don't understand it.

Comment: What are you studying in this course? From previous questions it seems that you are studying Fredholm alternative. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: For a), b) and c): Do I have the right approach? Are those correct?

Comment: Yes they are right. Just one thing, there is no need to say that $f\in C^0(\Omega)$. Just say that $u$ is a classical solution if it belongs to $C^0(\Omega)\cap C^2(\overline{\Omega})$ and satisfies $(I)$.

Comment: Thanks **Tomás**, hihi! What about the question: "d/ Determine the existence and uniqueness of solution of $(I)$ by $\lambda$". Can you have an ANS? I hope so :) !Hihi. Thanks!

"

Comment: How would you apply Fredholm alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: If $\lambda =0$ then I know, but I don't know if $\lambda \ne 0$ :( .

Comment: Yes, you know, you can do it. Translate this problem to the language of Fredholm alternative. What does Fredholme alternative says? When does Fredholm alternative guarantees existence or uniqueness?

Comment: I solved a,b, and c but I can't do d) . I have stuck when I'm trying to apply Fredholm's theorem, can you solve it? Thanks!

Comment: What text or book is that problem in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said in the comments that c) is solved, hence I will start from it. Let $S:L^2(\Omega)\to H_0^1(\Omega)$ be the solution operator associated with the problem $$
 \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
 -\Delta u=f &\mbox{ in $\Omega$} \\
  u=0 &\mbox{ in $\partial\Omega$}
       \end{array} \right.\tag{1}
$$

i.e. if $Sf=u$ then, $u$ solves $(1)$ in the weak sense. Note that $-\Delta (Sf)=f$ for $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. We apply [Rellich–Kondrachov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem) to conclude that $S:L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ is compact. I wil leave to you to prove that $S$ is symmetric, which implies that $S=S^\star$.

Consider the problem $$f+\lambda Sf=u\tag{2}$$

where $f,u\in L^2(\Omega)$. Assume that for $u=0$ the only solution of $(2)$ is $f=0$, then the Fredholm alternative implies that for each $u\in L^2(\Omega)$, problem $(2)$ has a unique solution. Take $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and note that equation $(2)$ implies that $f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Apply $-\Delta$ in both sides to get $$-\Delta f+\lambda f=-\Delta u\tag{3}$$

Because the range of $-\Delta $ is $L^2(\Omega)$, we conclude from $(3)$ that for each $g\in L^2$ there exist unique $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that $$-\Delta u+\lambda u=g$$

Now we pass to the second alternative, i.e. assume that for $u=0$, there is a finite dimensional subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$ with solutions of $(2)$. Apply the Fredholm alternative. What can you conclude now?

Comment: Yes, you're very good at maths! Thanks **Tomás**!

Comment: I think for question b/ Definition of weak solution in the $W^{1,\ 2}(\Omega)$ space. We need $ u \in W_0^{1,\ 2}(\Omega)$ and $\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \overline{\nabla \eta}\rm dx + \lambda \int_{\Omega}u \overline{\eta} \rm d x=-\int_{\Omega}f \overline{\eta}\rm dx, \forall \eta \in W_0^{1,\ 2}(\Omega)$?????

Comment: Yes this is the definition. Are you considering complex functions or real functions?

Comment: Finding the conditions so that weak solution becomes classical solution: I rewrite as :) 
$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \overline{\nabla \eta}\rm dx + \lambda \int_{\Omega}u \overline{\eta} \rm d x=-\int_{\Omega}f \overline{\eta}\rm dx, \forall \eta \in W_0^{1,\ 2}(\Omega)$$ Whence $$\left \langle \Delta u, \eta \right \rangle-\lambda\left \langle u, \eta \right \rangle=\left \langle f,\eta \right \rangle$$ So $\Delta u-\lambda u =f $, because $u$ is continuous. Moreover, $u \mid_{\partial \Omega}=0$ (with $u \in C(\overline {\Omega})$)

Comment: For question c): We assume that $u_1, u_2$ are solutions of (I) when $\lambda=0$. Let $u:=u_1-u_2 \in  W_{0}^{1,2} \implies \Delta u =0$. We have $$\left ( \Delta u,u \right )=\sum \int \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \overline{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}}dx=\left \| \nabla \right \|^2_{L^2} \ge C_{\Omega}^{-2}\left \| u \right \|^2_{L^2}$$ (Friedrichs'ineq). So $\left \| u \right \|_{W^{1,2}}=0 \implies u=u_1-u_2=0.$ Is it correct, **Tomás**?

Comment: For question d) I think that we can use **Friedrichs'inequality**:  $$\left ( \Delta u,u \right )=\sum \int \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \overline{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}}dx=\left \| \nabla \right \|^2_{L^2} \ge C_{\Omega}^{-2}\left \| u \right \|^2_{L^2}$$??? Do you think so? **Tomás**

Comment: Dear @kimtahe6. It would be really great if we could talk in some way, because it is really hard to help you with your doubts only with this little comment place. Do you have Skype or something like this? I am not so good at english, but I think I can talk something.